# How to attach to an app on android phone from MacOS terminal using lldb?

Tags: android, macos, lldb

I am trying to attach to an app running on my android phone using lldb on my MacOSX. This [link](https://lldb.llvm.org/remote.html) explains a little but its not clear on how to deploy lldb on my android phone. It explains a little about lldb-server but I cant seem to find that file anywhere. I don't want to use android studio because the app I am trying to attach to is not mine. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You won't be able to attach to the app unless it has been installed as a debug release.

Comment: Could you tell how to connect to an android phone using lldb on terminal? The thing is the guy who used to work before me on this project made this app but some how all the source code is lost and I want to see what information I can get from this app.

Comment: Was the app compiled by the debugger?

Comment: Cant tell. I want to use save-core to see what is there in the memory of the phone when implementing this app.